# How to remove duplicates after join in SQL

Tags: join, sql-server-2012, duplicates

I am **very new** to SQL - be kind! I am trying to remove duplicates from this join. What is my next step?! I know to use `select distinct` but not sure where...

```
SELECT 
    ac.[dc_id] 
    ,center_name
    ,ecec 
    ,inspec_date
    ,facility_type
    ,sitetype
    ,new_sitetype
FROM 
    usrbesp.wrk_city_active_sites ac
INNER JOIN 
    usrbesp.t_gdc_activity a ON ac.dc_id = a.dc_id  
ORDER BY
    dc_id
```

Comment: No idea--it was a "suggested tag" this is my first time using this site...

Comment: Is better mark only the tag related to your db .. and is a good pratice remove the not proper tag ..  and for remove duplicate you could use   select distinct

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `DISTINCT` but keep in mind that it is distinct against all columns in the `SELECT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     ac.[dc_id] 
    ,center_name
    ,ecec 
    ,inspec_date
    ,facility_type
    ,sitetype
    ,new_sitetype
FROM usrbesp.wrk_city_active_sites ac
inner JOIN usrbesp.t_gdc_activity a
ON ac.dc_id = a.dc_id  
order by dc_id
```

Comment: This gave me the same output as if I didn't use the distinct

Comment: @Katherine2 then the rows must be unique across all columns and not exact duplicates.